# Difference between 1:10 and 0.1:1.0

Tags: r, numeric

I was wondering why R sees `(1:10)` as an vector counting from 1 to 10 
And `(0.1:1.0)` as 0.1?

Should i define the steps from 0.05 by myself? or is there a trick to do this?

Comment: I. Know it's short, but please post working code examples with outputs for the two cases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The colon makes a sequence from the first number to last with steps of exactly `1`. Since in `0.1:1` that is less than one step it only returns the first number. I think you are looking for `seq(0.1,1,length=10)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `0.1 * (1:10)`.  It's (imho) clearer to read and easier to remember than the seq syntax, and while it may involve more processing is fine for everyday.

Comment: Yeah this works fine if you want to have 10 steps in 1 but that was just an example i need steps of 0.05 within the range of 0.5:0.95
But thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah that would be `0.05 * (10:199)` which is less comprehensible!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Its nice to see how many ways there are to perform something